# boto3 list all security groups for AWS account

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Is there any way to list all AWS security groups using boto3 ?

With this code i can get only 5 groups (out of 25 in region)

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')

response=client.describe_security_groups(



)
print response
```

I have 4 VPC's so i tried to get groups for each VPC, added this as filter:

```
Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'vpc-id',
            'Values': [
                'vpc-d60ee9b1',
            ]
        },
    ],
```

But as results i got this:

```
{u'SecurityGroups': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '44f39633-4f21-4c4f-b3f4-82fbce538c5f', 'HTTPHeaders': {'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'AmazonEC2', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Thu, 03 May 2018 08:25:03 GMT'}}}
```

Tried to filter by region and got:`The filter 'region' is invalid`

However, with AWS CLI it works:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --region $REGION
```

Does it means i need to stick with AWS CLI or boto3 has syntax  to list ALL security groups for AWS account ?

Comment: Ideally, describe_security_groups() boto3 call returns all the security groups in the region. However, if you set MaxResults, it will return the that number of results. This value can be between 5 and 1000. Can you confirm that this is not being set. You can define a logger to print debug logs from the boto3 call to identify if this is being set or not. Another way to check that is if the response contains `NextToken` key.

Comment: MaxResults is not set,how to print debug logs ?

Comment: To print debug logs, add the following line: `boto3.set_stream_logger('botocore', logging.DEBUG)`. Check the following line in your logs: 2018-05-03 10:33:50,683 botocore.endpoint [DEBUG] Making request for OperationModel(name=DescribeSecurityGroups) (verify_ssl=True) with params: {'body': {'Action': u'DescribeSecurityGroups', 'Version': u'2016-11-15', 'MaxResults': 5}, 'url': u'https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/', 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', 'User-Agent': 'Boto3/1.7.0 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/17.5.0 Botocore/1.10.2'}, 'context': {'auth_type'

Comment: I see all security groups when using boto3's describe_security_groups() method and they match the results of the awscli. Make sure that you have up to date boto3/botocore libraries and that you are actually querying the same account/region in both cases.

Comment: @jarmod, the problem with boto3 is don't know how to specify region ?

Comment: Example: boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')

Comment: yes, that's it, work now,in boto3 documentations weren't able to find it.Thanks @jarmod

Comment: The boto3 documentation is challenging to navigate, for sure. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: thanks @jarmod, really helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be describing resources in a different region. That's a common reason for things not showing up.

You can set the region as follows:

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')
```